# Twitter OAuth iPhone problem

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, twitter, build

I'm adding a twitter module on my program for both iPhone and iPad.
And I have met two problems.

---

1st, on iPhone.
After I merged my twitter module to my iPhone program, **build fails only in Debug mode.** It's ok in Release mode.

The error message is simply

```
Libxml/xmlreader.h: No such file or directory
```

Yes, it is because gcc can't locate it.
But I have added `-lxml2` for Other Linker Flags, and `/usr/include/libxml2/**` for Header Search Paths in project build settings on Release and Debug mode both.

---

2nd, on iPad.
After I merged twitter module to iPad program, build fails with the message below.

```
ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MGTwitterEngine in 
/Users/eddy/Documents/iOS/workspace/.../i386/MGTwitterEngine-3460BD6C4381A3AC.o and  
/Users/eddy/Documents/iOS/workspace/.../i386/MGTwitterEngine-CC42501E82512F61.o

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 
failed with exit code 1
```

I can't figure out the reason why this message comes.
Is the readymade module only for iPhone?
Or how can I fix it?

Comment: just to confirm : have you added libxml2.dylib and libz.1.2.3.dylib frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add "/usr/include/libxml2" in the header search path field of your project settings.
2. You have added the 2 files of same name(here MGTwitterEngine) to the same target.

Comment: Thank you Nithin. I solved 2nd problem. I didn't know there was some same files in my project because I was adding some additional functions in the project that another programmer made.
But 1st one, I have already added '/usr/include/libxml2' as recursive search and that looks linke '/usr/include/libxml2/**'.
Is there any suspects?